# How to override or disable a specific filter when testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need filter to be enable when testing as some are really important for my application logic, there for in my test setup i have `Route::enableFilters();` Now the problem is that i have added a CSRF filter on the top of that and now my test are breaking.

Is there a way to overide or disable the CSRF filter when testing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just turn off listener for this filter:

```
Event::forget('router.filter: csrf');
```

Answer (score 1):

One way (although admittedly not the most elegant) would be to check for the "testing" environment in your CSRF filter:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function($route, $request)
{
    // are we in the testing environment? if so, don't bother with the
    // token value
    if(App::environment()=="testing")
        return;

    // check the CSRF token
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
        throw new \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
});
```